# Множественная форма для требующих проверки сообщений

Tags: предложение, локализация, очередь-проверок, нет-в-transifex

В [статистике очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), которая выглядит примерно так:

[image: Статистика проверок]

для требующих проверки сообщений [нет множественных форм](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265556?key=c9187d8b8d769a79c9333b846aecb8d4). Предлагаю её добавить, т.к. для проверок за сегодня/всё время такие формы имеются.

Comment: Напишите лучше свой вариант ответом

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант:

> 1
>   сообщение для проверки

> 2
>   сообщения для проверки

> 5
>   сообщений для проверки

Comment: Не только вопросы. Например, `Запоздалые ответы`.

Comment: @alexolut: Угу. Тогда удалю лишнее.

Comment: [Добавили множественные формы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3921/176217). Теперь стоит вопрос, как Ваш вариант согласовать с другими полями (проверки за сегодня, проверки за всё время). Видимо, всё же слово "сообщение" тут не совсем подходит и должно быть именно существительное "проверка".

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю идти от вопросов, а не от проверок:

> 1 [вопрос] требует проверки
>
> 2 [вопроса] требуют проверки
>
> 5 [вопросов] требуют проверки

Comment: Проверять можно не только вопросы.

Comment: @alexolut там и не будет слова "вопрос".

Comment: @NickVolynkin а что тогда будет? `1 требует проверки`?

Answer (score 0):

Русифицированные варианты могут выглядеть так:

> 1 проверка требуется

> 2 проверки требуется

> 5 проверок требуется

Answer (score 0):

> 1 проверка в очереди

> 2 проверки в очереди

> 5 проверок в очереди

Comment: Проверка - это действие. Мне кажется оно не может быть элементом очереди. Например, если заменить на "диагностика" (считай, синоним "проверки") будет более очевидно, что такой вариант не подходит.